# Why do I get the error: Value of type 'Auth' has no member 'useEmulator'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth) tutorial to try and set up the Firebase emulator suite. However, I get the following error: Value of type 'Auth' has no member 'useEmulator'. Here is my code:

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase
import IQKeyboardManager

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        // code block used for local testing where error is showing
        let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
        settings.host = "localhost:8080"
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
        settings.isSSLEnabled = false
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        Functions.functions().useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://localhost:5001")
        Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost:"localhost", port:9099)
        //
        IQKeyboardManager.shared().isEnabled = true
        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '12.0'


target 'Pikit' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Pikit
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Functions'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
    pod 'FirebaseUI', '~> 8.0'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
    pod 'FirebaseUI/OAuth' # Used for Sign in with Apple, Twitter, etc
    pod 'FirebaseUI/Phone'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager' # Auto move screen for keyboard
    pod 'SDWebImage', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'PureLayout'
  
end
```

I have tried to build and clean my folder but that did not work. I think that I am not putting the provided code in the proper place but there is no indication within the documentation as to where it should go.

Comment: Do you have the Firebase/Auth pod installed?

Comment: @GarrenFitzenreiter Yes I do, I will edit to include my podfile.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, but I'm not sure why it's saying that, but I can assure you I've added that line to my project in the same place you did and it let me built it.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Firebase Auth (I think it's 7.2.0)? It could be the case that earlier versions use a different way to initiate the emulator use.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me and I found out my firebase pods were completely out of date. Was solved after I updated to the latest (currently for me it's 8.12 for Firebase/Auth)

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anybody. Cocoapods was not installing the latest Firebase SDK.

In your Podfile: 
Bump the min SDK: `platform :ios, '14.0'`

Change to `pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '~> 7.0-beta'`